# Rspec should.have not working without Spork

Tags: rspec2, spork

We're using Spork with Rspec and if we run Spork, our tests pass, but if we don't start spork and run the test with:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

Several failures occur, and all of them are the ones using the should.have syntax like:

```
inactive_user.received_messages.should have(1).message

1) Message introduction messages to active users should be created as messages to both users
 Failure/Error: initiator.sent_messages.should have(1).message
   expected 1 message, got 6
```

What's interesting about the number is that that's how many messages are in the database total, so :

```
initiator.sent_messages.should have(1) == Message.count
```

Without Spork, if I modify the test like:

```
inactive_user.received_messages.count.should == 1
```

everything works fine. So it seems like the matching method is looking at the wrong count. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: I haven't seen this before, and have no idea what's going on. Would you please file a bug report at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I am using shoulda gem to test relationship. I have Instance class that has many WeeklyStatistics and the first time I run :

```
should have_many(:weekly_statistics)
```

with spork the test was red indicating that I should set up foreigh key instance_id to the weekly stats but after I have done it the test still failed with the same error - missing association. Then I stopped spork and the test was green.